# what are the common techniques to create Python binding for a C++ project?

Tags: python, c++, c++11

I've seen so many projects written in pure `C++`, but when the project is done, authors create Python bindings for the project such that users could not only use the tool from command line but also inside python as a library.

I wonder how the Python binding is created?

Comment: I have seen good work done to wrap C++ with Python using boost python (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) as well as SWIG (http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html).  You can also manually write the bindings yourself if desired by using ctypes (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) but in that case you first need to have a pure C interface to wrap (not C++).

Comment: @qexyn, `pure C interface to wrap`? You mean I cannot have C++ class wrapped?

Comment: Only in the case of using python cyptes do you need pure C interface; sorry for confusion.  Boost python and SWIG allow binding to C++ directly so you dont need to write the C code.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options as you can see in the comments.

- Python / C API.
- Boost.Python
- Pybind11

There is [a talk](https://youtu.be/bJq1n4gQFfw) on CppCon 2016 about this that can be of interest to you.